# EOFError: end of file reached with Net::HTTP Post in Production Server Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ssl, https

Here is my code to post value in my localhost which is running in server:

```
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost:4000/')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == "https"
headers = 'email='+email
resp = http.post(uri.path,headers)
json_obj = JSON.parse(resp.body)
if(json_obj['prediction'] == 'important')
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

The code works perfectly in my local machine but not working in server production, some people suggest me to add `http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == "https"` but this still gives me error `EOFError: end of file reached` ,how to solve this error ? anyone come with solution in this error would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: try `resp = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path,headers)`

Comment: That is my first attempts and failed that's why i changed my code like in my question above

Comment: did you try a simple `curl http://localhost:4000/` from terminal on the server? Does it work?

Comment: ever get this to work?